# Is this Python Class mutable?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, mutability

Is this object mutable?

```
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
    def print_time(self):
        print(self.time)

boston_clock = Clock('5:30')
paris_clock = boston_clock
paris_clock.time = '10:30'
boston_clock.print_time()
```

It prints "10:30" even when I have expected to print "5:30" because strings are unmutable. Compared to code:

```
a = "Hello"
b = a
b += " World"
print(a)
```

it prints "Hello".
The object Clock behaves as a list so I think it is mutable but I dont know why. And in that case, how can I make the Clock class unmutable?

Comment: In a simple class like `Clock` the properties are mutable. You have to take additional steps like detecting assigning values to mutable properties, there is no inherent protection of class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are indeed immutable, however, in your example, you are changing not a string variable, but an object's attribute. The attribute referrers to a value, so by re-assigning it, you just make it pointing to another value.

Python is a very dynamic language and it's hard to make something really protected from a sudden mutation. However, there is a convention to use `_` at the beginning of an attribute name indicating that it's not supposed to be accessed and/or modified by any code outside of the class. And if you still want to have *public* `time` attribute, you can make it a property:

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, time):
        self._time = time

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self._time

    def print_time(self):
        print(self._time)
```

**UPD:** By the way, in Python variables are not so different from attributes. To access `my_clock.time` the interpreter needs to make some internal lookup of an attribute with the name `time` in a symbol table (just a fancy name for a dictionary) corresponding to the `my_time` object. At the same time, when you are accessing the local variable `a`, a similar lookup is being performed in another symbol table (aka dictionary) corresponding to the current local scope. Try out this snippet:

```
a = "Hello"
b = a
b += " World"
print(a)

locals()['a'] = "foobar"
print(a)
```

Even though strings are immutable, the second print outputs `foobar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to enforce something like your expected behavior you could use a getter/setter pattern:

```py
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
        self._time = time
    @property
    def time(self):
        print(self._time)
    @time.setter
    def time(self, value):
        raise AttributeError("Clock time does not support re-assignment")
```

Usage:

```py
>>> c = Clock("5:30")
>>> c.time
5:30
>>> c.time = "10:30"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in time
AttributeError: Clock time does not support re-assignment
```

You could also just `pass` instead of raising an exception, but that would potentially come off to some as code "failing silently" when they otherwise expected the attribute to be changed.

That said: to @IvanVelichko's answer, the underlying `_time` attribute can still be reassigned to if the user wants to go out of their way to do that:

```py
>>> c._time = "10:30"
>>> c.time
10:30
```

More broadly, the getter/setter pattern is used much less frequently in Python than something like Java for the reason shown above.